# SQL Command combining rows from a field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to combine rows from one table with my query in MS SQL on server 2008. I pulled this code off here I believe. This almost fits my needs but it is grouping the serial numbers off of SOPartsUsed but I need it to group based off tblServiceOrders.ProjectKeyID. Any help would be greatly appreciated I don't know much about SQL. I will leave a more detailed explanation of what I am trying to accomplish below.

```
SELECT        
p1.ItemID, SerialNumbers AS SerialNumber 
FROM            
tblSOPartsUsed p1 INNER JOIN
tblServiceOrders p2 ON p1.SONumber = p2.SONumber
    CROSS APPLY
       (SELECT        
        stuff
           ((SELECT ',' + p3.SerialNumber
             FROM tblSerialNumbers p3
             WHERE p3.FKSOPartsUsed = p1.SOPartsUsedKeyID
             ORDER BY SerialNumber FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
    ) D (SerialNumbers)
 WHERE        (p1.QuantityFilled > 0) AND (p2.ProjectKeyID = 385)
 GROUP BY p1.ItemID, SerialNumbers, p2.ProjectKeyID
 ORDER BY p1.ItemID
```

I have a table with serial numbers a table with parts used on a service order and a service order table.

tblSerialNumbers -> tblSOPartsUsed -> tblServiceOrders

**tblSerialNumbers**
*itemID  SerialNumber  FKSOPartsUsed*
1          1444                233
1          1555                234
1          1666                236

1          1999                237
1          1888                238

1          2222                239
1          2121                240

**tblSOPartsUsed**
*itemID  SOPartsUsed  SONumber  QuantityFilled*
1          233                  SO544         5
1          234                  SO544         7
1          236                  SO544         7
1          237                  SO577         7
1          238                  SO577         7

1          239                  SO581         7
1          240                  SO580         7

**tblServiceOrders**
*SOnumber  ProjectKeyID*
SO544        PJ366
SO577        PJ366
SO580        PJ111
SO581        PJ111

What I would like
itemID   ProjectKeyID   SerialNumber
1           PJ366             1444,1555,1666,1999,1888

What I get
itemID   ProjectKeyID   SerialNumber
1           PJ366             1444,1555,1666
1           PJ366             1999,1888

I am trying to group serial numbers and item id's by ProjectKeyID found in tblServiceOrders. Right now the query above works but it is grouping ItemID's on the tblSOPartsUsed and want to group on ProjectKeyID.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: can't you just move the `p2.ProjectKeyID` to an earlier position of the `GROUP BY` clause, e.g. the first position?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried it and it doesn't work. The issue I think is I need to group the cross apply select by itemID. itemID is in Serial Numbers table. Right now it seems to be grouping them based on service orders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  itemID ,
    ProjectKeyID ,
    ( SELECT    SerialNumber + ', ' AS 'data()'
      FROM      dbo.tblSOPartsUsed u
                JOIN tblSerialNumbers nbr ON u.SOPartsUsed = nbr.FKSOPartsUsed
      WHERE     SONumber IN ( SELECT    SOnumber
                              FROM      dbo.tblServiceOrders
                              WHERE     ProjectKeyID = tso.ProjectKeyId )
                AND itemID = tso.itemID
    FOR
      XML PATH('')
    )
FROM    ( SELECT DISTINCT
                c.itemID ,
                ProjectKeyId
      FROM      dbo.tblServiceOrders a
                JOIN dbo.tblSOPartsUsed b ON a.SOnumber = b.SONumber
                JOIN dbo.tblSerialNumbers c ON b.SOPartsUsed = c.FKSOPartsUsed
    ) tso
```

I don't think I totally understand what you're trying to accomplish with itemID - having only one distinct value in the sample makes it hard to verify results - but this might get you closer

Comment: Awesome this worked. I am trying to pull itemID's in a specific project and group their serialnumbers into one field. I'm new to stackoverflow. I feel like Pabloker helped me make my question more clear but Jim your solution is the answer. Is what are some of the things I can do on here to help with that credit?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT        
p1.ItemID, p2.ProjectKeyID,D.SerialNumbers AS SerialNumber 
FROM            
tblSOPartsUsed p1 INNER JOIN
tblServiceOrders p2 ON p1.SONumber = p2.SONumber
CROSS APPLY
   (SELECT        
    stuff
       ((SELECT ',' + p3.SerialNumber
         FROM tblSerialNumbers p3
         WHERE p3.ItemID = p1.ItemID
         ORDER BY SerialNumber FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
) D (SerialNumbers)
WHERE        (p1.QuantityFilled > 0) AND (p2.ProjectKeyID = 'PJ366')
GROUP BY p1.ItemID, p2.ProjectKeyID, SerialNumbers 
ORDER BY p1.ItemID
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried it and it doesn't work. The issue I think is I need to group the cross apply select by itemID. itemID is in Serial Numbers table. Right now it seems to be grouping them based on service orders.

Comment: Could you put all the fields with data used in the query? I'm trying to replicate your environment. For example `tblSOPartsUsed.QuantityFilled`, `tblSOPartsUsed.ItemID` and so..

Comment: I think I've done what you requested. I just removed item description from my query  as it's not important. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I also added quantity filled in the table data

Comment: Ok, but `tblSOPartsUsed.ItemID` still missing in the table definition. Could you add it?

Comment: Try this..change the line `WHERE p3.FKSOPartsUsed = p1.SOPartsUsedKeyID` for this `WHERE p3.ItemID = p1.ItemID`. I changed the answer too.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That sort of works. Problem is it pulls all itemIds from tblSerialNumbers and I need just ones that are in tblSOPartsUsed. I've updated my table data to show what will happen.